# Squared norm of matrix equal to squared norm of its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

With the definition of matrix norm as

$$\|M \|=\sup_x \{  |Mx|: |x|=1 \},$$

where $M$ is square and $|\cdot|$ denotes the standard euclidean 2-norm. I'm trying to prove that

$$\|M\|^2=\|M^T\|^2 = \mathrm{largest \; eigenvalue \; of \;} M^TM?$$

Comment: The title isn't accurate.

Comment: @Git Gud - how's this?

Comment: The relevant thing in the question is proving it equals the largest eigenvalue, not that it equals the norm of the transpose (that will be an easy consequence).

Comment: note that this is true only if M is orthogonally diagonalizable, for example `M=[2 1 ; 0 1]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\|Mx\|^2 = (Mx)^T(Mx) = x^T(M^TM)x
$$

Comment: So similarly we have

$$||M^Tx||^2 = x^TMM^T x,$$ I'm not sure where you would go from here though.

Comment: Re my previous comment, for real matrices $M$ we have $M^TM=MM^T$ ...

Comment: @DaveS: As Git Gud and copper.hat note, the next thing to note is that $M^TM$ and $MM^T$ always have the same eigenvalues, since $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues for arbitrary matrices $A,B$.

Comment: I know that the derivative of $||x||_2^2$ w.r.t $x$ is equal to $2x$. But what about the derivative of $||x^T||_2^2$ w.r.t $x$. Is it the same $2x$? or $2x^T$?

Comment: @DavidSimmons This is an old thread.  But in case someone is confused by $M^TM=MM^T$ as I did.  This is not true, and can be easily checked, e.g. Let $M$=[1 1; 0 0], where the ';' separates two rows. Then $M^TM$=[1 1; 1 1], but $MM^T$=[2 0; 0 0].  They do have the same eigenvalues though.

Answer (score 6):

Show that the non zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same. (In this case $A=M,B=M^T$).